# how to handle new page on button click in pupeteer?

Tags: node.js, typescript, puppeteer

i am using puppeteer in a project to test a web page , in the page i have several buttons that open a new tab in the browser , how can i handle that using puppeteer?

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async() => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ defaultViewport: null });

    const page = await browser.newPage();

    // go to the URL
    await page.goto('https://example.com/', {waitUntil: 'networkidle'});

    await page.click('.btnId'); //opens new tab with Page 2

    // handle Page 2
    // process Page 2
    // close Page 2

    // go back to Page 1

    browser.close();

})();
```

how can i handle the page 2 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
await page.waitFor(3 * 1000)  // wait for new page to open
const pages = await browser.pages()  // get all pages
const page2 = pages[pages.length - 1]  // get the new page
// process the new page
await page2.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps in solving the problem.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async() => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ defaultViewport: null });

    const page = await browser.newPage();

    // go to the URL
    await page.goto('https://example.com/', {waitUntil: 'networkidle'});

    await page.click('.btnId'); //opens new tab with Page 2

    // you can make this as dynamic as well depends on the website and use case.
    const [tabOne, tabTwo] = (await browser.pages());

  // use the tabs Page objects properly
  console.log("Tab One Title ",await tabOne.title());

  // use the tabs Page objects properly
  console.log("Tab Two Title ",await tabTwo.title());

    // you can use close property for tab when it's done.

    browser.close();

})();
```